# Unshortener URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, url-shortener

this is my first time unshortenering a url and i have encountered http://expandurl.appspot.com/ that allow my shorten url to expand. Using jquery ajax, it does not seem to return any value. Please help. Thanks

```
var url = "http://expandurl.me/expand?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2FjcelX0";
        alert(url);
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: "GET",
            success : function(data) {
                alert("Successful");
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));

            }
        });
```

Comment: expandurl.me service seems to be offline

Answer (score 0):

It won't work: You're running into JavaScript's same-origin policy, which makes it difficult (but not impossible) to access data from a different domain. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy.